# Spring Boot Notified by database for any change in values

Tags: database, oracle, spring-boot, triggers, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot app. i need to hit the db/run a query every 15 secs to check the values of a status column.
Now i would like to check the below possibilities instead of querying the data every 15 secs

1. any mechanism , where database will notify the app automatically without querying explictly (trigger etc?)  if yes , please share a sample example

Comment: Do you have multible applications running on the same database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking at is commonly known as [CDC (change data capture)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_data_capture) and is a widely used software design pattern.

There are some commercial tools like [Oracle GoldenGate](https://www.oracle.com/middleware/technologies/goldengate.html), [Hevo](https://hevodata.com/) that implement CDC for Oracle database. Alternatively, there are also some an open-source tools such as [JDBC Connector for Kafka](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-connector/source_config_options.html) and [Debezium](https://debezium.io/roadmap/) (with a [community developed connector](https://github.com/erdemcer/kafka-connect-oracle)) you might want to have a look at.

Almost all of the above-mentioned tools publish the captured data changes as events to Kafka. So, you will need to integrate your application with a Kafka cluster.

Comment: To add to this, Debezium can also be used as [a library embedded](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/development/engine.html) into a Java application itself which seems like a good fit for this use case. In this case, Apache Kafka isn't needed, you'll need to take care of persisting connector offsets yourself only.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the operations over time, you can specify a trigger. There is another strategy perhaps one could follow is to keep track of the size of the schemas. For instance,

```
SELECT table_name ,
  round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024), 2) as SIZE_KB
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE table_schema = DATABASE();
```

This query will list the schema table row's along with their respective sizes in Kb's/Mb's. One can probably frame a service class underneath and keep a track of the change in size and update the service in charge in an interval of say 25 seconds.

This could come in handy!
[image]